# Printing out a random string (Python)

Tags: python, random

I am asked to produce a random string using a previously defined value.

```
THREE_CHOICES = 'ABC'
FOUR_CHOICES = 'ABCD'
FIVE_CHOICES = 'ABCDE'

import random

def generate_answers(n: int) -> str:
    '''Generates random answers from number inputted '''
    for i in range(0,n):
        return random.choice(FOUR_CHOICES)
        continue
```

What I am trying to get happening here is, if I were to plug in 7 into the function I'd get something like 
"ABDCBBA"

A random 7 character string from the specified letters. However, this code is returning only one random character no matter what number I put in (has to be non-zero).

I don't know what to do here, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `return` is the end of your function.  Always.  So accumulate in some manner, and then `return` the accumulated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested, but should work.

```
THREE_CHOICES = 'ABC'
FOUR_CHOICES = 'ABCD'
FIVE_CHOICES = 'ABCDE'

import random

def generate_answers(n):
    '''Generates random answers from number inputted '''
    answerList = ""
    for i in range(0,n):
        answerList += random.choice(FOUR_CHOICES)
    return answerList
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just return a list like this:

```
def generate_answers(n):
    '''Generates random answers from number inputted '''
    randoms = [random.choice(FOUR_CHOICES) for _ in range(0,n)]
    return randoms
    #return ''.join(randoms) to get string

print generate_answers(7)
```

this would print a list like this: `['D', 'D', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C']`

you could `join` the list if you want a string

Comment: @EricCuevas No problem! good luck with the rest of the project :)!