# How to print a random string in separate lines

Tags: python, string, random, printing

I need help on how to display the result of the following code in separate lines:

```
import random

import string

random.choice(string.ascii_letters)

random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for n in range(3)])

print (random.lower())
```

I've made several searches to find help, like this:
[Printing out a random string (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391080/printing-out-a-random-string-python)

But it only tells me how to create and print a random string (like this: a, b, c) but not like this (which is what I need):

```
a
b    
c
```

I use python 3.6.0 by the way.

Comment: If you want the three choices to be displayed separately, why do you combine them into one single string? And if you want them all lowercase, why include capitals in the initial choices? Also note that you don't assign the result of your first choice, so that line is redundant.

Comment: firstly don't use variable name same as modules imported..

Comment: Because of ignorance really. I thought it would be possible. How tried copy pasting a part of the code 3 times but got an error, so figured it wasn't the right way (im a newbie)

Comment: advay = good point.

Comment: You can use '\n'(next line char) in your code like
 `random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters)+'\n' for n in range(3)])`

Comment: Thank you so much Ming Chu it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import random
import string

output = '\n'.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for n in range(3)])

print (output.lower())
```